# wix product id should be autogenerated for patch number changes?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

I use wix for building a setup for a product. The product has version of the format

```
major.minor.patchnumber
```

Example:

```
4.5.1313
```

in each build the last patchnumber keeps changing like 1314, 1315 and so on.

I would like to know whether I should keep the id attribute in the [product](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_product.htm) element as [autogenerated](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_simple_type_autogenguid.htm) between just the patch number changes or should they remain constant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are autogenerating your Product/@Id then you are doing a Major Upgrade. If you want to do small updates or minor upgrades then you do **not** want to change the Product/@Id.

See the table in this topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(VS.85).aspx